# assembly instruction vs text as steam of binary read by processor, delimiter question

Tags: assembly, binary, machine-code

I understand that assembly language instructions will eventually be translated to binary, eg. **5F** **3A** **E3** **F1**, and processor has a set of [instructions tables](https://www.atarimax.com/jindroush.atari.org/aopc.html).

But, when reading a stream of binary how does processor/computer knows when instructions begin or when actual text message begins/ends?

Text messages can be a simple 'Hello World' or a mix with characters that happens to be **5F**(-) **3A**(:) **E3**(ã) **F1**(ñ) or **0xa**(line-feed)

If anything can be mapped to ASCII tables then **terminating**/**delimiter** character/s that marks the end of text message can be mis-interpreted as being part of the text message instead of becoming a real instruction since there is no limit of how long text can be nor limitation of what characters we can put as text message.

Comment: The processor doesn't know if something is code or data. It's up to the programmer/compiler/linker to organize the executable in such a way that only actual code will get executed.

Comment: The next instruction begins right after the end of the previous one.  (Or at a branch target).  Variable instruction-length machine code like x86 is typically not self-synchronizing; tools like disassemblers need to know a valid starting point.  Don't put your data where it will be executed as code.

Comment: how does a train steer?  it follows the tracks that have been laid out in front of it. no different on a processor there is a known starting point and the programmer must insure there are a valid path of instructions from that point forward, not necessarily linear, you can jump, just like train tracks can have a fork and take one of two paths.  If you examine the binary in execution order from the known/agreed entry point then  there is no confusion whatsoever (if it is a properly constructed program).